# Why isn't my module data getting picked up in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm trying to create my first module and believe I've ended up confusing myself somewhere.

I am testing a variable called `ami_key`. I have set a default value in my `variables.tf` file as:

```
variable "ami_key" {
    type        = string
    description = "Key Pair"
    default     = "key-default"
}
```

But in my module I defined it as:

```
module "compute" {
  source        = "./module/dev"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  name_tag      = "VM"
  env           = "dev"
  number_of_instances   = 1
  ami           = "ami-0a3c3a20c09d6f377"
  aws_region    = "us-east-1"
  ami_key       = "key"
}
```

Now my basic understanding is that the `ami_key` defined in my module `compute` will override the default value in `variables.tf`, but that doesn't happen when I run `terraform plan`, the key is set to the `variables.tf` default value:

```
  + key_name                             = "key-default"
```

What am I missing or doing wrong here as I expect the output to be:?

```
  + key_name                             = "key"
```

My structure of my directory is:

```
Terraform_EC2
  |-main.tf
  |-provider.tf
  |-variables.tf
  |-output.tf
  |-module
    |-dev
      |-compute.tf
```

`main.tf`

```
provider "aws" {
    access_key  = var.aws_access_key_id
    secret_key  = var.aws_secret_access_key
    region      = var.aws_region
}

resource "aws_instance" "aws_vm" {
    ami             = var.ami
    instance_type   = var.instance_type
    count           = var.number_of_instances
    key_name        = var.ami_key

    tags = {
        ec2_dev_name    = "${var.name_tag}${var.env}${count.index}"
    }
}
```

`module/dev/compute.tf`

```
module "compute" {
  source        = "./module/dev"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  name_tag      = "VM"
  env           = "dev"
  number_of_instances   = 1
  ami           = "ami-0a3c3a20c09d6f377"
  aws_region    = "us-east-1"
  ami_key       = "key"
}
```

`variables.tf`

```
variable "instance_type" {
    type        = string
    description = "Instance Type"
    default     = "t2.micro"
}

variable "name_tag" {
    type        = string
    description = "Name"
    default     = "VM"
}

variable "env" {
    type        = string
    description = "Environment of EC2"
    default     = "dev"
}

variable "number_of_instances" {
    type        = number
    description = "Instances"
    default     = 1
}

variable "ami" {
    type        = string
    description = "AMI ID"
    default     = "ami-0a3c3a20c09d6f377"
}

variable "aws_region" {
    type        = string
    description = "US East 1"
    default     = "us-east-1"
}

variable "ami_key" {
    type        = string
    description = "Key Pair"
    default     = "key-default"
}

variable "aws_access_key_id" {}

variable "aws_secret_access_key" {}
```

`providers.tf`

```
terraform {
    required_providers {
        aws = {
            source  = "hashicorp/aws"
            version = "~> 5.27.0"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code looks good. It could be some cache issue. Try deleting the .terraform directory and re-run the plan. Also make sure that the path to module is correct, and that the source files are saved.

Comment: I deleted the .terraform directory and then ran `terraform init` after which I ran `terraform plan` but I still get the default value for `key_name`

Comment: @Dan where are you running `terraform plan` from? Which directory are you in?

Comment: I am running `terraform plan` at the top I'm in the `Terraform_EC2` directory. I'm running this on a linux server.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. The module is in `/dev/`, but you are not referencing it in the `main.tf`?

Comment: oh! I wasn't aware. I assumed Terraform loads everything. How would I reference it?

Comment: @MarkoE comment is best guess that you are executing `terraform` from within the declared module directory, and not within the root module directory, and that would cause the value to be incorrect within the declared module. However, I do also notice an analogous resource within the root module config using the root module `ami_key` variable value. Therefore what is most likely occurring here is confusion between the resource in the root module and the resource in the declared module. Please add resource namespacing from the plan output to confirm this is root cause.

Comment: It is also possible there is a typo in the question and you switched the configs for `main.tf` and `module/dev/compute.tf`. Please clarify that also.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm having a hard time to understand as my knowledge is weak at the moment. I will read up on namespaces. I am definitely in the main directory where `main.tf` is kept and running terraform from there.
I'm not sure what switch means here. I've listed the configs as they currently are on my lab environment. Any hints on what I should be looking for here?

Comment: @Dan, It appears you have got things mixed up. What you have in main.tf would be the module source file. And what you have in compute.tf should use path to where main.tf is for module source. You must be applying the terraform from where the compute.tf is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your understanding of modules and their paths is a bit mixed up/incorrect.
Below is how you could keep your files for use of the module:

```
|-module
  |ec2
    |-main.tf
    |-provider.tf
    |-variables.tf
    |-output.tf
|-dev
  compute.tf
```

Within compute.tf, you can use the ec2 module like below:

```
module "compute" {
  source        = "../module/ec2"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  name_tag      = "VM"
  env           = "dev"
  number_of_instances   = 1
  ami           = "ami-0a3c3a20c09d6f377"
  aws_region    = "us-east-1"
  ami_key       = "key"
}
```

You run your terraform apply from the dev folder. Let us know if you face any issues after this.

Comment: This is brilliant advice and now I see I was understanding completely incorrectly the way to think about modules. I thank you very much for showing the light!!